# I'm trying to combine multiple images into one "flowing" video with "flowing" music, using and automated process

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, images, automation

(command line), randomization, and bulk processing ability

I'm aware of some tools like ffmpeg and ImageMagick, but I don't quite know the easiest or the most eloquent way to do this, and I've been scouring the internet unsuccessfully trying different things like mad. The stuff that I have found is very, very old.

My dilemma is as follows: out of each folder, I want to be able to choose only 3 image files at random (there will be more than 3 image files in these directories). If there are less than 3, process only what's available. Combine them into something that resembles a stylish composition, preferably one fading out into the others after 3 seconds have passed for each image.

On top of that, I'd like to add an audio track from a *randomly selected* audio file located in a different directory. And I want the music from the audio file to begin playing at a random point in that particular audio file, minus at least 9 seconds (3 images x 3 seconds = 9 seconds.. I don't want the audio to stop before the video stops)

This all has to be done automatically and in real time and no file folder that contains an image should be processed more than once. I have only some knowledge of programming. Definitely a bit overwhelmed. So anyway, do you think it's possible?

Comment: `ffmpeg` can do what you want, but this will require scripting to automate it. Your OS and preferred scripting/code language is unknown.

Comment: Python, or even better (for me) batch files/powershell.

Comment: Your question is too broad with multiple questions. I doubt you'll get a comprehensive answer because an answerer has to know powershell, how to deal with randomization, and ffmpeg. It works best on this site if you ask 1 question per post: each post focusing on a specific problem or step. So I recommend you [edit] this question to ask about the `ffmpeg` part specifically, and then ask new questions (possibly on [SO]) regarding the scripting.

Comment: The title will still interfere, and must be more specific. I suppose I'll delete this and ask a new question. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: The title can be edited too.